# How do I get if something is near using proximity sensor in android with QML

Tags: android, qt, qml, proximitysensor

I'm trying to use the `ProximitySensor` in QML. I didn't find examples of how to use it. I'm using QtSensors 5.0. I tried get if something is near by calling the `reading` property, but this property only have this properties: `deleteLater`, `objectName` and `timestamp`. I tried this `ProximityReading.near`, but it returns undefined. I also tried this `proximitySensor.close()`, but it returns that proximitySensor was not defined. The proximity sensor is working fine, because I tested in my smartphone the property `reading.timestamp` and the values was updated properly.

My code is something like this:

```
import  QtSensors 5.0
ProximitySensor {
    id: proximity
    active: true
    dataRate: 100

    onReadingChanged: {
        // How do I get if something is near?

    }

    onErrorChanged: {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type info may not be property interfaced to be read by Creator, but the properties and methods should be there nonetheless. Try this:

```
onReadingChanged: {
     if (reading.near) console.log("it is near")
     else console.log("it is far")
}
```